# Why are \new... defined as \outer in the plain TeX format?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

In `plain.tex`, D.E.Knuth decided to define as `\outer` all the macros which allocate registers: `\newcount`, `\newdimen`, `\newskip`, `\newread`, `\newwrite`. This forbids them from entering the argument of macros, or definitions: they can only appear at the outer-most level.

On the other hand, Leslie Lamport has mostly dropped the `\outer` primitive when writing the LaTeX format. In particular, the allocation macros are not `\outer` anymore in his approach.

What are the advantages and drawbacks of both choices? What about other formats (ConTeXt, LaTeX3)?

As a side question: is there some historical piece of folklore associated to the `\outer` primitive?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The primary purpose for `\outer` is to catch errors, such as carelessly allocating registers or streams in a macro definition or forgetting the closing brace of a `\long` macro argument. One often sees

```
\newcommand{\xyz}[1]{...\newlength{\xyzlen}\setlength{\xyzlen}{#1}...}
```

which is *bad* programming; this can't happen in Plain TeX (with `\newskip` or `\newdimen`, of course) because those macros are `\outer`. Why is it bad programming? Because at each call of `\xyz` a new register called `\xyzlen` will be allocated and the old ones forgotten and unusable. One can think to `\xyzlen` as a variable that's allowed to receive a value: thus

```
\newlength{\xyzlen}
\newcommand{\xyz}[1]{...\setlength{\xyzlen}{#1}...}
```

would do the same work and be much more efficient.

One has to remember also that the original TeX had 256 registers of each type and only 16 input and output streams. So sparing them was essential and declaring the `\new...` macros as `\outer` helped in avoiding register misuse. It would be bad programming anyway, even now that e-TeX provides 32768 registers of each type.

However, `\outer` usage has some drawbacks: `\outer` macros can't appear in the middle of skipped conditional text, so

```
\ifdefined\xyzlen\else\newdimen\xyzlen\fi
```

is invalid in Plain (pdf)TeX, once `\xyzlen` has been defined.

Another example: it's hard to define Plain TeX macros on top of `\beginsection` or `\proclaim`, say to add automatic numbering.

In my opinion, allocation macros *should* be outer. There are a few cases where this can be a nuisance. For example, a package that defines new kinds of floats will use `\newcounter` in the definition. It would be easy to provide an "inner" version `\@newcounter` to be used in packages

```
\outer\def\newcounter{\@newcounter}
\def\@newcounter#1{<what LaTeX does now>}
```

Plain TeX, for instance, says `\outer\def\+{\tabalign}` so we can use `\tabalign` in definitions involving simple alignments. At least this will catch errors in defining commands by inexperienced users.

However there's always the old trick of saying (as I learned to do in the olden days)

```
\newcount\thmcnt
\def\theorem{\advance\thmcnt 1
  \csname proclaim\endcsname \number\thmcnt\ }}
```

that avoids TeX seeing the forbidden control sequence and `\theorem` would behave in a similar way to `\proclaim`. But anyone that knows about `\csname` qualifies as `experienced user', if not TeX wizard.

An alternative route is suggested by Bruno in his comment:

```
\edef\innerproclaim{\noexpand\proclaim}
\newcount\thmcnt
\def\theorem{\advance\thmcnt 1 \innerproclaim\number\thmcnt\ }}
```

that works because the expansion of `\noexpand\proclaim` is performed before assigning the result as the meaning of `\innerproclaim` and the `\noexpand` in front makes TeX see, at assignment time, a control sequence equivalent to `\relax`, that's allowed to be in a replacement text. Again, `\edef` and `\noexpand` *cognoscenti* qualify as experienced users.

Comment: Agreed, I wish I could upvote it twice (still, my upvote is a marginal increase in egreg's rep anyway;)).