# 'Runaway definition' error when a token list variable is defined inside a macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, token-lists

The following plain TeX manuscript

```
\def\mymacro{\newtoks\mytoks}\bye
```

fails to compile and generates the following error:

```
Runaway definition?
->
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \mymacro.
<inserted text> 
                }
<to be read again> 
                   \newtoks 
l.1 \def\mymacro{\newtoks
                         \mytoks}\bye
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 232 of `plain.tex` has

```
\outer\def\newtoks{\alloc@5\toks\toksdef\@cclvi}
```

Look in the TeXbook for `\outer`. Page 206, first doubly dangerous paragraph:

> The `\par`-forbidding mechanism doesn’t catch all conceivable missing-brace errors, however; you might forget the `}` at the end of a `\def`, and the same problem would arise. In this case it’s harder to confine the error, because `\par` is a useful thing in replacement texts; we wouldn’t want to forbid `\par` there, so TeX has another mechanism: When a macro definition is preceded by ‘`\outer`’, the corresponding control sequence will not be allowed to appear in any place where tokens are being absorbed at high speed. An `\outer` macro cannot appear in an argument (not even when `\par` is allowed), nor can it appear in the parameter text or the replacement text of a definition, nor in the preamble to an alignment, nor in conditional text that is being skipped over.

See also [Why are \new... defined as \outer in the plain TeX format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32356/why-are-new-defined-as-outer-in-the-plain-tex-format) and [Why is \newcount declared \outer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173901/why-is-newcount-declared-outer)

If you really need to do `\newtoks` as part of a plain TeX definition:

```
\def\mymacro{\csname newtoks\endcsname\mytoks}
```

will do.