# How to get width of parameter in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, lengths, parameters

I am trying to get the width of a macro parameter using

```
\def\getwidthof#1{%
    \newdimen\myl%
    \settowidth\myl{#1}%
    \the\myl%
}
```

where `\settowidth` is defined as

```
\catcode`\@=11
\newbox\@tempboxa
\def\@settodim#1#2#3{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}#2#1\@tempboxa
   \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
\def\settoheight{\@settodim\ht}
\def\settodepth {\@settodim\dp}
\def\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}
\catcode`\@=12
```

using egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52861/what-is-the-plain-tex-equivalent-of-settowidth). I would like the code `\getwidthof{some text}` to print out the width of `some text`, which in this case would be `42.55563pt`. The code

```
\newdimen\myl
\settowidth\myl{some text}
\the\myl
```

works, but breaks when a parameter is used. Is it because `#1` is not expanded when put in `\settowidth\myl{#1}`?

Comment: To start with, `newdimen` inside a command definition is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Okay that's indeed the issue.

Comment: By the way next time include the error message in the question itself. Easier for answerers to spot the issue

Comment: See also: [tex core - Why are \new... defined as \outer in the plain TeX format? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32356/why-are-new-defined-as-outer-in-the-plain-tex-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error or not, your code is wrong anyway. You're allocating a new `\dimen` register each time you're calling `\getwidthof` and wasting resources.

Let's see with an error-free definition:

```
\def\getwidthof#1{%
    \csname newdimen\endcsname\myl%
    \settowidth\myl{#1}%
    \the\myl%
}
\catcode`\@=11
\newbox\@tempboxa
\def\@settodim#1#2#3{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}#2#1\@tempboxa
   \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
\def\settoheight{\@settodim\ht}
\def\settodepth {\@settodim\dp}
\def\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}
\catcode`\@=12

\getwidthof{abc}
\getwidthof{def}
\getwidthof{ghij}

\bye
```

The log file will have

```
\@tempboxa=\box16
\myl=\dimen16
\myl=\dimen17
\myl=\dimen18
```

Fixed code.

```
\catcode`\@=11
\newbox\@tempboxa
\def\@settodim#1#2#3{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}#2#1\@tempboxa
   \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
\def\settoheight{\@settodim\ht}
\def\settodepth {\@settodim\dp}
\def\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}
\catcode`\@=12

\newdimen\myl
\def\printwidthof#1{%
  \settowidth{\myl}{#1}%
  \the\myl
}

\printwidthof{abc}

\printwidthof{def}

\printwidthof{ghil}

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This also will helps:

```
\newbox\mywidthbox%
\newdimen\mywidthdimen%

\def\getwidthof#1{%
\setbox\mywidthbox=\hbox{#1}%
\mywidthdimen=\wd\mywidthbox%
}

\getwidthof{test}

\showthe\mywidthdimen


\getwidthof{long test}

\showthe\mywidthdimen


\bye
```

> > 16.16669pt.
>
> > 37.8334pt.